# difficulties in writing function which returns the intersection of two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have tried to write a function which finds the intersection of two arrays

and I just cant understand why it does not work well. Here is my function:

```
int* IntersectionOfArrays(int* arr1, int size1, int* arr2, int size2, int* sizeRes) 
{
    int* res=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));  //res is the array of the resolution of intersection//
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    *sizeRes = 0;

    merge_sort(arr1,0, size1-1);  //sorting the arrays//
    merge_sort(arr2,0, size2-1);

    while (i < size1 && j < size2) 
    {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
            i++;
        else if (arr1[i] > arr2[j]) 
            j++;
        else 
        {   
        res[*sizeRes] = arr1[i]; //getting the same elements of the two arrays - the intersection values//
        i++;
        j++;
        (*sizeRes)++;
        res = (int*)realloc(res, 1*sizeof(int)); //allocating more memory as required - according to the size of res(intersection)//
        }   
    }

    if (*sizeRes==0)  //if the intersection is empty 
        return NULL;
    return res;
}
```

This function compiles, but does not work as expected since I get junk items..
I wonder how this function should be repaired.

Comment: `res = (int*)realloc(res, 1*sizeof(int));` --> `res = realloc(res, (*sizeRes + 1) * sizeof(int)); `

Comment: Suggest initially allocating the minimum of `size1 * sizeof int` and `size2 * sizeof int`.  That's the maximum you can need.  If you wish, shrink that allocation after the loop, when you know the needed size.  As a bonus, if the intersection is empty then `realloc()`ing to size zero frees the whole allocation, thereby fixing the memory leak from which your current code suffers.

Comment: Also `return NULL;` : You have memory leak.

Comment: when calling `realloc()`, always save the returned value into a temporary pointer, then check (!=NULL) that pointer to assure the operation was successful.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the original pointer is lost, resulting in an un-recoverable memory leak

Answer (score 2):

```
res = (int*)realloc(res, 1*sizeof(int)); 
//allocating more memory as required - according to the size of res(intersection)//
```

But on contrary to what your comment suggests, you are not increasing the size of your array. But instead, you are again allocating memory for only one integer again. Try the following:

```
res = realloc(res, (*sizeRes + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

Additionally, use a temporary pointer while using `realloc()`

```
int* temp = realloc(res, (*sizeRes + 1) * sizeof(int));
if(temp == NULL) {
    //handle unsuccessful memory reallocation
}
else {
    res = temp;
}
```

By doing this you can use `res` even if reallocation fails.